# How to automatically make a NoneType into a string?

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

This is my code:

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
from pprint import pprint

laz = Share('LAZ') #Lazard
# ABERDEEN
amg = Share('AMG') #Affiliated Managers Group
ben = Share('BEN') #Franklin Resources
lm = Share('LM') #Legg Mason
evr = Share('EVR') #Evercore Partners
ghl = Share('GHL') #Greenhill
hli = Share('HLI') #Houlihan Lokey
mc = Share('MC') #Moelis
pjt = Share('PJT') #PJT Partners
ms = Share('MS') #Morgan Stanley
gs = Share('GS') #Goldman Sachs
jpm = Share('JPM') #JP Morgan
ab = Share('AB') #Alliance Bernstein

print ("Lazard: $" + laz.get_open())
# ABERDEEN
print ("AMG: $" + amg.get_open())
print ("Franklin: $" + ben.get_open())
print ("LeggMason: $" + lm.get_open())
print ("Evercore: $" + evr.get_open())
print ("Greenhill: $" + ghl.get_open())
print ("Houlihan: $" + hli.get_open())
print ("Moelis: $" + mc.get_open())
print ("PJT: $" + pjt.get_open())
print ("MorganStanley: $" + ms.get_open())
print ("Goldman: $" + gs.get_open())
print ("JPMorgan: $" + jpm.get_open())
print ("AllianceBernstein: $" + ab.get_open())
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ballz/Documents/Python/PDF to Excel/StockPerformance/stockcompetitoranalyis.py", line 26, in <module>
    print ("Houlihan: $" + hli.get_open())
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
```

However, it is really weird becuase it works half the time, and the other half it does not. Why do the rest work, but this specific one does not?

Comment: Try casting: `str(hli.get_open())`

Comment: What do you want to happen in that instance? Should it print `'None'`, an empty string (`''`) or something else?

Comment: The NoneType object (None, because that's the only object of type NoneType) has nothing to do with the string you want, and it cannot be used to retrieve the string you want. Calling `str` on it will only produce the string `"None"`.

Comment: Maybe the data wasn't available. Maybe you hit a rate limit or something. Whatever the case is, you don't have the data.

Comment: Using the `str().format()` method will not throw the error, but nevertheless the string will just read 'None', that is because theres no data and the `get_open()` method returns None in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work..

Just use this function `Share_nonesafe` instead of `Share`

```
from yahoo_finance import Share

def Share_nonesafe(x):
    if Share(x) == None:
        return (' price not available.')        
    else:
        return (Share(x))
```